# Question about charge and discharge of a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, discharge, charge, slew-rate

Let's consider the following amplifier:

[image]

and suppose that a capacitor is connected between the output node and ground.
Let's suppose that the inverting terminal becomes much larger than the non-inverting one (i.e. I'm considering a situation which triggers the slew-rate condition). The situation becomes the following:

[image]

Indeed, the differential pair gets unbalanced and behaves like a current switch. The dc current (blue arrows) of transistor M9 can only flow through M2, M4 and the capacitor, being the other transistors turned off. This dc current discharges the capacitor.

**Question:** I have never thought to the following doubt, but yesterday suddenly it came to my mind. Assume that, before the unbalancement (i.e. in the quiescent condition), Vdd is 1.8 V and the output dc voltage is 900 mV. When the inverting terminal becomes much larger than the non-inverting one, the current discharges the capacitor. But how is it possible that the blue arrow through the capacitor has that direction? The current must always go from higher potential to lower potential. But here the discharging current goes from ground to 900 mV!

Comment: Current does not always go from higher to lower potential; that's only true in the case of a resistor.

Comment: What @Hearth said, plus -- during that time when the cap has a positive charge, it's acting like a voltage source.